# MySql : Convert Column data to row

Tags: mysql, unpivot

I have a table in mysql which looks like below.

```
id  cust_id date    data

1   1   1/1/2018    a b c d e f g

2   1   2/1/2018    h I j k l m n
```

Here in this example data column is having huge data seperated by space like a b c d, I would like to show case as in row like below

```
id  cust_id date    data

1   1   1/1/2018    a

1   1   1/1/2018    b

1   1   1/1/2018    c

1   1   1/1/2018    d

2   2   2/1/2018    h

2   2   2/1/2018    i

2   2   2/1/2018    j

2   2   2/1/2018    k
```

I have checked few option like using unpivot function, but unable to achieve my output.
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: You really should store the data in your database in the second format, and then produce the first format if/when desired using `GROUP_CONCAT()`.  As things stand, this isn't easy to reverse within MySQL alone—suggest you write a little ETL script to do it for you.

Comment: So data is always one char + one space?

Comment: @eggyal for your quick reply,
What if I am not allowed the change the way DB tables are stored.
Do you see any potential way which can help me to get expected o/p.
As I need to read the data column values
Thanks !!

Comment: @davidbaumann Yes, its always separated by one space, and its not one char, it is having numeric number, which can be in decimal format too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
  tablename.id,
  tablename.date
  ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tablename.data, ' ', numbers.n), ' ', -1) name
from
  (
    SELECT @row := @row + 1 as n FROM 
    (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t,
    (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t1,
    (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t2,
    (SELECT @row:=0) r
  ) numbers INNER JOIN Table1 tablename
  on CHAR_LENGTH(tablename.data)
     -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(tablename.data, ' ', ''))>=numbers.n-1
order by
  id, n
```

Check link for output

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa0dcb/1

**EXPLANATION:**
First go through the inner query i.e.

```
select 0 
union all 
select 1 
union all 
select 3 
union all 
select 4 
union all 
select 5 
union all 
select 6 
union all 
select 6 
union all 
select 7 
union all 
select 8 
union all 
select 9
```

This will generate a table of 10 rows with 10 numbers.

Now the other query :

```
 SELECT @row := @row + 1 as n FROM 
    (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t,
    (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t1
```

Since above query is generating row numbers from below table 't' and table 't1' which is separated by ',' means that they are producing Cartesian product of their total rows.
For example: t have 10 rows and t1 also have 10 rows so, there Cartesian product produces 100 rows. So @row variable incremented 100 times and gives 100 rows of 100 numbers from 1 to 100.

The below query:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tablename.data, ' ', numbers.n), ' ', -1)
```

this one will take "a b c d e f g h" one by one.

For example:
take `numbers.n = 1`
then inner substring_index will find index of first space and will return string before that index i.e. `'a'`
and then outer substring_index will find the space from the end of the resulting string and will give the last character from the string i.e. `'a'`.

Now if you
take `numbers.n = 2`
then inner substring_index will find index of first space and will return string before that index i.e. `'a b'`
and then outer substring_index will find the space from the end of the resulting string and will give the last character from the string i.e. `'b'`

Always try to breakdown the query like this and you will able to understand the query in simpler way.

Comment: @ Jay Shankar Gupta:  Thanks for your answer.
I have query here :
1. What is the significance of multiple (select 0 union all select 1...) statements, as if I keep one then Output is same only.
2. Here in this example value in data column is small like only till g which is 7 char, but in real this column may have data upto 100 char.
Hence I feel it does not make sense to write this statemnt upto 100 chare or whatever be the count in real time.
((select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 ...) 
Thanks !!

Noticed you have edited your answer with one statement :) Thanks

Comment: no need of writing upto 100  `SELECT @row := @row + 1 as n FROM 
    (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t,
    (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t1,
    (SELECT @row:=0) r`

Comment: the above query will give upto 100

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0e64/2 check link if you repeate `(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t` line n times you will get upto 10^n

Comment: And there are 256 ASCII characters so you need 3 repetition of that line

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am not very expert in SQL, and if I want to understand this query, can I debug , or how should I execute step by step to understand what this whole query is doing. Appreciate your reply !!

Comment: I am also not an expert in SQL but i always break any sql query into smaller parts and then try to understand each and every part like i explained above.@pargrng