# how to convert comma separated string to single column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Table:

```
id    brand    group
1     adidas    1,2
2     puma      1
3     asianone  1,2,3
```

what result i want:

```
id    brand    group
1     adidias  1
2     adidias  2
3     puma     1
4     asianone 1
5     asianone 2
6     asianone 3
```

where id is autoincrement..

Comment: Have you tried anything? From where you are getting those data?

Comment: question is too broad, you could either fetch all the rows, break them apart, then create a csv then import it, or you could break it apart again then insert it into another table with a similar or exact copy of the source table structure and insert it there

Comment: you want insert in another table or you want show result in page

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT @id:=@id+1 AS id,
       `brand`,
       `group` 
FROM
(SELECT
  `id`, 
  `brand`,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`group`, ',', n.digit+1), ',', -1) AS `group`
FROM
  Table1
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT 0 AS digit 
   UNION ALL SELECT 1 
   UNION ALL SELECT 2 
   UNION ALL SELECT 3  
   UNION ALL SELECT 4 
   UNION ALL SELECT 5 
   UNION ALL SELECT 6) n
  ON LENGTH(REPLACE(`group`, ',' , '')) <= LENGTH(`group`)-n.digit
  Order by ID,`group`) AS T,(SELECT @id:=0) AS R;
```

**Output**

```
id  brand   group
1   adidas      1
2   adidas      2
3   puma        1
4   asianone    1
5   asianone    2
6   asianone    3
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be29c2/31

**For Explanation goto this link and check my answer**

> [MySql : Convert Column data to row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49274506/mysql-convert-column-data-to-row/49274896#49274896)

Answer (score 0):

```
select
   brandstable.id,
   brandstable.brand,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( brandstable.`groupname`, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) `groupname`
from
  (select 1 n union all
   select 2 union all select 3 union all
   select 4 union all select 5) numbers INNER JOIN brandstable
  on CHAR_LENGTH(brandstable.groupname)
     -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(brandstable.groupname, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1
order by
  id, n

replace your tablename with brandstable.
```

[image]

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. Share some of your expert knowledge with us and help other programmers grow.

Answer (score 0):

Please use PHP explode() function.It can breaks a string into an array.

Syntax:
'explode(separator,string,limit);'